# Process a dictionary and return each entry in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Basically I'm fetching data from my API, the data looks like this:

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "user": "user1"
      "text": "i'm a sample text1"
    },
    {
      "user": "user2"
      "text": "I'm a simple text2"
    },
}
```

I want to use only the 2 `comments['text']` entries and I want to render them to my HTML one by one, how should I achieve this?

```
componentDidMount() {
// Call REST API to get info on comments
fetch(this.props.url, { credentials: 'same-origin' })
  .then((response) => {
    //deal with response
  })
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      comment_text : data['text'],
    });
  })
}
```

and this is how I wrote my render function:

```
render() {
  // Render text for comments
  return (
    <div className="comments">
      <p>{this.state.data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how's your desire output will look like

Comment: are there more than 2 objects in your `comments` array?

Answer (score 0):

Use map as others said:

```
componentDidMount() {
// Call REST API to get info on comments
fetch(this.props.url, { credentials: 'same-origin' })
  .then((response) => {
    //deal with response
  })
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      comment_text : data,
    });
  })
}
render() {
  // Render text for comments
  return (
    <div className="comments">
           {this.state.comment_text["comments"].map((value,key)=>{
                  return (<p>{value}</p>)})}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keep your value to comments state and in render map loop through all ur data and set it in ur html. If it is a large html u better create a component for this Then u can call ur html inside render. I think this is pretty standard and clean way to render your dynamic data into ur view

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      comments: [
        {
          user: "user1",
          text: "i'm a sample text1"
        },
        {
          user: "user2",
          text: "I'm a simple text2"
        },
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const d = this.state.comments.map(item => {
       return (
          <div>
            <p>{item.user}</p>
            <p>{item.text}</p>
          </div>
        )
    })

    return (
      <div>{d}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

If your data is saved to `this.state` like this:

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "user": "user1"
      "text": "i'm a sample text1"
    },
    {
      "user": "user2"
      "text": "I'm a simple text2"
    },
}
```

... and you want it to render like this:

```
<div className="comments">
  <p>i'm a simple text1</p>
  <p>I'm a simple text2</p>
</div>
```

.. then what you're looking for in your render function is:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="comments">
      {this.state.data.comments.map((comment, index) => <p key={i}>{comment.text}</p> )}
    </div>
  );
}
```